# how to eliminate the same row adding in a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating a table with the add function .Here i want to remove the same data adding in that table.Each table row i set id but i want to check the row data is already exit in that table while adding.

```
function adddata(pos=''){
  var main_loc = $("select#drop2 option:selected").attr('value');
  var sub_loc = $('#drop3 option:selected').attr('value');
  $("#del_row").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "add_datas.php",
    type: "post",
    data: "main_loc="+main_loc+"&sub_loc="+sub_loc,
    success: function(result){
      $("#tab").show().html(result);

      var getDayArray = JSON.parse(result);
      var main_name=getDayArray[0][2];
      var sub_name=getDayArray[0][3];
      var map_label=getDayArray[0][4];

      var main_loc_id = $("select#drop2 option:selected").attr('value');
      var sub_loc_id = $('#drop3 option:selected').attr('value');
      var edit_id = "edit_"+main_loc_id+"_"+sub_loc_id;

      if(pos!="") {
        var table = document.getElementById("tab_grid");
        var row = table.insertRow(pos);
        row.id = edit_id;
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = main_loc_id;
        cell2.innerHTML = sub_loc_id;
        cell3.innerHTML = main_name;
        cell4.innerHTML = sub_name;
      } else {
        $('<tr id = "'+edit_id+'"><td>'+main_loc_id+'</td><td>'+sub_loc_id+'</td><td>'+main_name+'</td><td>'+sub_name+'</td><td>'+map_label+'</td><td>'+first_level+'</td><td>'+second_level+'</td></tr></table>').appendTo('#tab_grid');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please create a fiddle with all your code and explain in more detail what the code should do

Comment: `function adddata(pos=''){` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Also, what is the parameter `pos`? Why do you do the same thing both `if` branches once with jQuery and once without?